# Safe wallet gnosis is not receiving buy/sell tax rewards

Tags: safe-core

Currently I have wallets which are set up with safe wallet which hold tokens that get buy/sell rewards.  Since setting these wallets up the transfers of BNB rewards from the contract to the safe wallet deposits have failed and are now pending. Can you set the gnosis wallets up to where they can receive rewards from the contract without them getting declined or having to claim them manually?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please give more context on the error, like the addresses or transaction hashes that fail?

There is no restrictions in the code to prevent safes from receiving tokens. Maybe the error comes from the reward contract? If the error comes from Safe, you can find the list of error codes [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account/blob/main/docs/error_codes.md).

It could be also that the reward contract calls a function on the Safe that has not been implemented; in which case the call is forwarded to the [compability fallback handler](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account/blob/main/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol). Maybe the problem comes from here.

Without more details it will be difficult for us to pinpoint what is going wrong.